# Расширение при сохранении файла в Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

После очередного обновления Notepad++ произошёл непонятный глюк. Раньше при сохранении файла "Сохранить как" и выборе "Тип файла", например [image: пример]

автоматически добавлялось расширение, например "имя файла.html", сейчас надо прописывать вручную. Это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Думаю, об этом нужно писать на страницу или почту поддержки Notepad++. Куда-то сюда: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/category/4/help-wanted

Comment: А мы вряд ли сможем с этим помочь, это же просто фича приложения. Откатить версию можете, там версий 7 последних доступны.

Comment: поставьте [sublime text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) и кучу плагинов в придачу получите

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Перед тем как собрался писать выставляешь нужный синтаксис, и тогда при сохранении автоматом подставляется нужное расширение.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте галочку "Скрывать расширение для зарегистрированных типов файлов". Попасть в неё, к примеру, из W7 можно через любое окно проводника - "Упорядочить" - "Параметры папок и поиска" - "Вид".

Answer (score 0):

В более ранних версиях, в 6.8.3 например, автосохранение нового файла идёт в .txt, в новых версиях файл по умолчанию не получает расширения (All types).